# Is Firefox 6/7 handling max-width:320px media query wrong?

Tags: firefox, media-queries

I'm seeing strange behavior with media query in Firefox lately, and I was wondering who's doing it right (compared to Chrome and IE9).

I've got the following css:

```
@media screen and (max-width:320px){
#sfWrapper{max-width:280px;font-size:0.625em;line-height:1.2em}
#cpw_banner{display:none;visibility:hidden;}
#cpw_content{width:100%;}#cpw_aside{width:100%;}
}
```

And Firefox (when resizing the browser, doesn't seem to notice the max:width 320px while it reacts to the bigger screen media queries.

Not only that, but when I use ctrl + often enough on a window it will kick in, where as Chrome and Internet Explorer 9 don't apply new media queries on ctrl + / ctrl -

---

Anyone know what's the 'standard' behavior with regards to ctrl+/ctrl- and media queries?

Thanks in advance...
J.

Comment: Extensions that augment the navigation bar (e.g., Firebug, Colorzilla, LastPass, Web of Trust) greatly worsen this problem. The simplest solution I've seen among the three Stack Overflow questions related to this problem is the one from @john-aspinall below. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821329/why-does-firefox-have-a-min-width-minimum-of-615px and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286680/media-min-width-not-being-recognised-by-firefox-8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Firefox, depending on your exact toolbar setup, it may be impossible for the content area to shrink below a certain width.  If you set up a page with a vertical scrollbar, you can see the scrollbar start disappearing when the window gets to be smaller than that minimal width.  At that point, the browser window is getting smaller, but the page viewport is NOT.  So if that minimal width is greater than 320px in your case, then the media query above would never apply.

The key point being that media queries match on the page viewport width, not the browser window width.

Furthermore, media queries match on CSS pixels, not device pixels.  Zooming in Firefox changes the size of a CSS pixel in device pixels, so the page viewport size (which is fixed in device pixels) changes in CSS pixels.

There is no standard of what zoom should do.

Comment: Thanks! would have been nice if everyone handled zoom identically for a change...

Answer (score 7):

I dont know why the answer provided has been ticked as it doesn't answer the OP's question.  The reason why the media query doesn't fire 320 pixels is because of the navigation toolbar in Firefox.

If you turn it off (go to VIEW - TOOLBARS - NAVIGATION TOOLBAR and untick it) then the media query will fire at 320 pixels.

Comment: Euhm... well that's what he said no?

Depending on toolbar setup, the viewport can't shrink below the 320px and that's why the media query didn't fire. Maybe it wasn't clear to you, but to me as the OP I understood perfectly what Boris meant, hence the answer flag... J.

Comment: I agree that this answer is more clear and succinct, though since they're both helpful I upvoted both. BTW, you can very quickly toggle the nav toolbar in Windows: just hold ALT and press V, T, N. I assume something similar works for Mac (maybe Command).

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on a responsive design for 320px but Firefox just wouldn't respond.

I found that, for some reason, if you set your media query to 480px - `(max-width:480px)` - then Firefox will apply the media queries anyway.