# @media min-width not being recognised by firefox 8

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, mobile, media

I have been using media queries for the first time, and things going well, but seem to have encountered a strange problem.

here is my css:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:768px) { /* tablet portrait */
   css here
}

@media only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:480px) { /* mobile landscape */
   css here
}

@media only screen and (max-width:320px){ /* mobile portrait */
   css here
}
```

Everything works fine in Chrome, and the stylesheets are implemented as expected. In firefox, hoever, the last stylesheet (max-width:320px) isn't picked up.

I've done alot of searching and can't find anything similar.

Very appreciated if anyone has any advice...

Comment: Yes, it should. I've changed that in my code and it makes no difference. Will change in the above.

Comment: Closest answer I could find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663005/is-firefox-6-7-handling-max-width320px-media-query-wrong

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. It's not urgent, as  I don't need the mobile styling to show up in firefox, just made me nervous when something was happening that I couldn't find a reason for!

Comment: Yea, I go through the same thing. Always good to know for sure.

Comment: Extensions that augment the navigation bar (e.g., Firebug, Colorzilla, LastPass, Web of Trust) greatly worsen this problem. The best solution I've seen among the three Stack Overflow questions related to this problem: View > Toolbars > Hide the navigation toolbar. See also [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821329/why-does-firefox-have-a-min-width-minimum-of-615px].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super late here, but just change the

```
@media only screen and (max-width:320px){ /* mobile portrait */
    css here
}
```

to

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){ /* mobile portrait */
    css here
}
```

For some reason, firefox won't recognize anything below 480px, so if we change the 320px to 768px it will act as the default value, while the more precise queries will override it.

Edit: Make sure the overriding element are BELOW the iphone's in the CSS.

Comment: I've just wasted far too long wondering my max-width:320px media query wouldn't trigger in Firefox. I read this, tried Chrome and it works. Grrr. -1 Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my experience to this; I was having the same issue but it turned out disabling the Firebug addon made it behave as it should. I'm using FF 15 (mac). Firebug 1.10.03

I suggest disabling all addons at first to see if it works, then turn them back on one by one.